# Zooming and scrolling in Oxyplots

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I have a question about zooming and scrolling. My scroll function doesn't work perfectly, but close enough. Instead of the Maximum value I want to change the ActualMaximum, but that one was protected.

```
plotBSITotalA.Model.Axes[0].Maximum = hScrollBarA.Value + 
  (plotBSITotalA.Model.Axes[0].ActualMaximum - plotBSITotalA.Model.Axes[0].ActualMinimum);
plotBSITotalA.Model.Axes[0].Minimum = hScrollBarA.Value;
```

Ok, here comes the real problem: When I have zoomed in or out, the scroll function won't work anymore in that specific plot Area, where it have been zoomed. Other plotArea's that weren't zoomed, will work perfectly.

Does somebody know, how I can scroll when I zoomed in??

Comment: can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: No I've not enough reputation to post images ;)

Comment: oh ... ok ... put it on any sharing images site (imgur.com for example), and then put a link then ...

Comment: No not yet, but the priority of the project has changed and i'm at the moment busy with something else. As soon as i have time i will show the screenshots ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be, It can be done by connecting two enevts with two methods:
1. event emitted when scrollbar changed with method of changing axes range 
2. event emitted when axes range changed with  method of changing the scrollbar position

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few views, so maybe still a problem.

As I understand it, your saying the auto scroll stops when you have zoomed back out and subsequently add new values to the series?
Can't find a formal solution, but this works for me

add this to your axis:

```
xAxis.AxisChanged += OnXAxisChange;
```

add the method

```
 bool doAxisReset = false;
 private void OnXAxisChange(object sender, AxisChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      //if zoomed fully out, then enable auto scroll
      //
      if ((e.DeltaMaximum == 0) && (e.DeltaMinimum == 0))
      {
        doAxisReset = true;               
      }
  }
```

In the rendering code (ie when you get a new element that triggers autoscrolling) and before InvalidatePlot

```
if (doAxisReset)
{
      xAxis.Reset();
      doAxisReset = false;
}
```